# How to retrieve all values in serialized array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

i'm trying to get all values in this array stored in wp_option table.
The array is:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:11:"development";i:1;s:4:"apps";i:2;s:10:"creativity";}
```

What i need is just to get the values: **development**, **apps**, **creativity**.

I was trying:

```
$myOptions = get_option('hashtag');
foreach($myOptions as $option) {
echo $option;
}
```

but the output is:

```
developmentappscreativitydevelopmentappscreativitydevelopmentappscreativity
```

If i write:

```
var_dump ($option);
```

the output is:

```
string(11) "development" string(4) "apps" string(10) "creativity" string(11) "development" string(4) "apps" string(10) "creativity" string(11) "development" string(4) "apps" string(10) "creativity"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And `var_dump($myOptions)`?

Comment: `array(3) { [0]=> string(11) "development" [1]=> string(4) "apps" [2]=> string(10) "creativity" } array(3) { [0]=> string(11) "development" [1]=> string(4) "apps" [2]=> string(10) "creativity" } array(3) { [0]=> string(11) "development" [1]=> string(4) "apps" [2]=> string(10) "creativity" } `

Comment: Then you obviously run your code three times. Please check it again.

Comment: Code run only once.

Comment: But you got your output __three__ times. This means that either your code runs __three__ times with same data or your data has __nine__ values.

Comment: And some `echo 'Foreach over';` after your `foreach` and see how many times your code runs.

Comment: Code was wrongly running inside a function that give 3 output. Now resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$myOptions = get_option('hashtag');

echo $myOptions[0]

Comment: And what is this?

Comment: the output is now:
`0 development1 apps2 creativity0 development1 apps2 creativity0 development1 apps2 creativity`

Comment: It looks like the option is just an associative array. You should be able to retrieve the values by referencing the key, development. Apps, etc.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. I'm looking at it wrong. Is development the value, or should development be a reference to a value?

Comment: Is development the value

Comment: You can get the valuea by the index then. I've updated my answer. The array index startes at 0. So to get any value from the array you can do $myOption[0], $myOption[1], etc

Comment: echo $myOption[0];
it does not generate any output.

Comment: I was missing the "s". To get a value from an array, you need to specify the index. So referencing 0 will return the first value. Make sure the spelling for your variable is correct.

Comment: I got it! 

$myOptions = get_option('hashtag');

echo $myOptions[0].'<br>';
echo $myOptions[1].'<br>';
echo $myOptions[2].'<br>';

Thank you very much Harry!